# Beamer add captions below subfigures

Tags: beamer, subcaption, includegraphics

I have a slide in Beamer with two subfigures in the same row. I wish to place two captions, one for figure, below the figure (i.e., Leo Bremain (1928 – 2005) and Adele Cutler). I tried different solutions but everytimes I lost the figures alignment.

[image]

```
\frame{\frametitle{Random Forests}
    \justifying
    \scriptsize 
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[scale = 1]{Breiman2.png}}   
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[scale = 1]{Cutler.png}}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the package `subcaption`. (and images cropped from the posted figure)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}    
\usetheme{default}  

\usepackage{subcaption} %  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Random Forests}
        \begin{figure}[ht]
            \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                % first image
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{Breiman2}  
                \caption*{Breiman}
                \label{fig:Breiman}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                % second image
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{Cutler}  
                \caption*{Cutler}
                \label{fig:Cutler}
            \end{subfigure}
      \end{figure}  
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```